# npm start gives error `webpack-dev-server: not found` even if it is installed

Tags: reactjs, npm, installation, dependencies

In package.json `devDependencies` I have webpack-dev-server installed:

```
"webpack-dev-server": "3.2.1"
```

but when I run the start script, which looks as follows:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --config demo/webpack.config.js --port 9000 --mode development"
```

I get this error:

```
sh: 1: webpack-dev-server: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! your-app@2.0.5 start: `webpack-dev-server --inline --config demo/webpack.config.js --port 9000 --mode development`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the your-app@2.0.5 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that every script you want access in cli, script should be install in your system as globally.
you can install globally every script you want with `npm`. that way add `-g` in your command when you want install package.

In your case, you should run this command:

```
npm install webpack-dev-server -g
```

after that you can access `webpack-dev-server` in your command. like your code `webpack-dev-server` added to `start` script in your `package.json` file.

After that, you can run `npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev` command to add  this package in your `node_modules`.

Now, you have access `webpack-dev-server` in your cli. As you write in your `start` script in your `package.json`.

Comment: npm actually knows to look in its local binaries as well.

Answer (score 0):

My app by default, did a "production" install, which didn't install devDepencies.

I did:

```
export NODE_ENV=development
```

before executing `npm install` and it installed dev dependecies, so now it works.